# Import Youtube API data into db using Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, youtube-data-api, laravel-5.3

I am trying to build a Youtube based application with Laravel 5.3. Using a library I am able to successfully retrieve the data from a playlist and display it. It is formatted like this:

```
[
    {
        0: {
            kind: "youtube#playlistItem",
            etag: ""I_8x5t5r66_FSaexwefRREftGc0/BO3zvggHrzgTTh_ZhXr745ww"",
            id: "UExDQXc3VFJvaVBIX2VuXzMtcThnWW9ZZUc4YlVmX2dOUC4wMTcyMDhGQUE4NTIzM0Y5",
            snippet: {
                publishedAt: "2014-10-06T15:50:12.000Z",
                channelId: "UCGT2vvwtBJ-0edGHEj5Tv67Q",
                title: "S'More - La ricetta dei biscotti",
                description: "Sul blog la storia, la ricetta e le foto",
                thumbnails: {
                    default: {
                        url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Hug-iFvDS3s/default.jpg",
                        width: "120",
                        height: "90"
                     },
                     medium: {
                         url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Hug-iFvDS3s/mqdefault.jpg",
                         width: "320",
                         height: "180"
                     },
                     high: {
                         url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Hug-iFvDS3s/hqdefault.jpg",
                         width: "480",
                         height: "360"
                     },
                     standard: {
                         url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Hug-iFvDS3s/sddefault.jpg",
                         width: "640",
                         height: "480"
                     },
                     maxres: {
                         url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Hug-iFvDS3s/maxresdefault.jpg",
                         width: "1280",
                         height: "720"
                     }
                  },
                  channelTitle: "Ricette di Famiglia",
                  playlistId: "PLCAB2ddt6H_en_3-q8gRfTYsbUf_gNP",
                  position: "0",
                  resourceId: {
                      kind: "youtube#video",
                      videoId: "Hug-iFvDS3s"
                  }
               }
            },
...
]
```

My next step would be grabbing the array containing video related data, conveniently map each item to a Video class instance and finally store each video item into my database. Does anyone have any idea how can I acheive that?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the this by using the following. From the API response you have provided in your question, there is an array of objects, and those objects have objects inside them, so you will need two loops.

```
// $json is the JSON response you get from the API
$entities = json_decode($json);

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $items = get_object_vars($entity);

    // Each $item is a video object from the API response
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Create a new Video object and persist it in the DB
        $video = new Video();
        $video->create([
            'kind' => $item->kind,
            'published_at' => $item->publishedAt,
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```